# How to apply style for the horizontal bar displayed due to overflow auto like in facebook

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to apply the style for the scroll bar and which should show when the mouse is over the particular div.

-Lokesh.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean, or provide a better description?

Comment: Scrollbars can't be styled unless you use some javscript code or somethign like that. IE use to have some non-compliant css rules you could use and webkit too, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @elclanrs I have checked a similar query in stackoverflow, in which thwy have suggested to use webkit.http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ . Is there any specific reason not to use the webkit.

Comment: @NathanTaylor I need a scroll bar to be displayed when i mouse roll over the dic, which should not be in the windows style. I need to add my own style, like in facebook right side status updation area. I hope this shows more light on the query.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented before, to style scrollbars you should use javascript and let alone non-compliant browser css rules. Take a look at http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

For your other question, on how to show the scrollbar just when you hover your mouse on top of the overflown div you could do something like:

```
div { overflow-y: hidden; }
div:hover { overflow-y: auto; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6m3n7/2/